# How to resolve the collision due to same hashcode values of unequal objects while we try to insert them into HashSet?

Tags: java, collections

According to hashcode contract it shows that two objects which are not equal can contain same hashcode values. Therefore, if we are using `HashSet` which takes the hashcode value of the object as the index to store objects and how will it resolve the collision of filtering the right object?

Likewise I want to know is there any possibility to remove the previous object by the new object when we try to insert them into `HashSet`, since they got the same hashcode values **even if they are not equal** ?

I am a student following java and can anybody please help me to resolve this!

thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you want this? If the object are not equal then adding to the `Set` is the correct behavior.

Comment: It is explained pretty well here: [Collision Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An identical hash code coming from two different objects is no problem (unless it occurs frequently and/or many more times).

Hashing algorithms must be able to cope with that, and there are several strategies to do that. One is by *chaining* objects with identical hashcode into a list, the start of which is kept at the position resulting from the hash code.

Also, consider that the cardinality of hashCode is the same as of data type int, but your hash table will have necessarily only a "small" range of slot addresses; therefore the hashCode is always reduced (by some modulo operation) and this will create more collisions!

**Later**

As to the removal of a set element with the same hash code: You could do that by keeping track (in a Map) of all the hashCode values that have been entered so far. But to remove that other element will defeat the purpose of your Set - why was it added to the set in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Objects that are equal should (better: must) have the same hash code. Objects having the same hash code are not necessarily equal.

Hash data structures - such as `HashSet` or `HashMap` - use the hash code for fast determining the bucket in which the objects are stored. But they use the equality for determinig whether the object already is contained.

Answer (score 1):

> According to hashcode contract it shows that two objects which are not equal can contain same hashcode values.

Correct.

> Therefore, if we are using HashSet which takes the hashcode value of the object as the index to store objects and how will it resolve the collision of filtering the right object?

`HashSet` uses the hashcode of an object to index into an array, but this not an array of the objects that the `HashSet` contains. Instead, it is an array of *buckets*, each of which can contain multiple objects. In its simplest form, each bucket is a linked list. If multiple distinct objects end up in the same bucket, they are chained onto the linked list. These objects are distinguished using the `equals()` method.

> Likewise I want to know is there any possibility to remove the previous object by the new object when we try to insert them into HashSet, since they got the same hashcode values even if they are not equal?

(I think you mean "replace" instead of "remove".)

Suppose you're adding an object to a `HashSet` and there is already a different object present in the set that has the same hashcode as the one you're adding. The two objects will necessarily end up in the same bucket since they have the same hashcode. However, the `HashSet` code will call `equals()` on the objects to determine whether they're equal. Since they're not, the second object will be added to the same bucket as the first, but the second won't replace the first.

Wikipedia has a [pretty good article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) that covers a bunch of techniques for dealing with hash collisions.